# Как выборочно убрать пустую область с картинки с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Есть png изображение с пустой областью по краям (на скриншоте пустая область - это клеточки)

[image]

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы область сверху и снизу обрезалась, а по краям осталась?

[image]

Пока есть вариант пробегаться по каждому пикселю, если весь ряд пустой, то удаляем. Но может есть более простой способ?

Comment: object-fit: contain не подходит?

Comment: @Listopad02 не подойдет, потому что изображение находится в html канвасе и перед скачиванием его нужно обрезать сверху и снизу

Comment: думаю, более простого способа нет, можно оптимизировать по скорости, а фон прозрачный или все таки шашечки?

Comment: @DaniilLoban прозрачный

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример кода, к сожалению сниппет создать не удалось, но код работает относительно быстро, за счет метода массива `some`. Строка которая появилась сверху это новое изображение на `канвасе` нарисованное поверх оригинального (600x600 со словом "пример" в центре).

[image: пример работы кода]

- `loadImage` загужает изображение
- `getData` получает пиксельные данные (по четыре байта на пискель `rgba`) следует учесть что иногда данные изображения получить нельзя из-за того что оно будет находится в другом домене можно попробовать установить аттрибут `img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '')`
- в строке `line = data.data.slice(i, i + blockSize)`  мы вырезаем
  линию из изображения
- `(line.some(byte => byte !== 0))` проверяет что она не полностью пуста (иначе ни данных о цвете ни о прозрачности - все нули).
- зная начальную и конечные линии "непустого" изображения можем
  вырезать его `ctx.getImageData(0, top, width , newHeight);`.
- и отрисовать новое изображение `ctx.putImageData(trimmedImage, 0, 0)`

```js
function loadImage (imageUrl){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      resolve({img, width: this.width, height : this.height})
    }
    img.src = imageUrl;
  })
}

function getData(ctx, width, height){
  try {
    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
  } catch(e) {
    return null; // ошибка получения данных
  }
}

function trimTransparent(ctx, width, height){
  const blockSize = width * 4
  const data = getData(ctx, width, height)
  if (!data) return null
  const length = data.data.length;
  const filledLines = [];
  let i = 0;
  let lineNumber = 0 
  while (i < length) {
    lineNumber += 1
    line = data.data.slice(i, i + blockSize)
    if (line.some(byte => byte !== 0)) {
      filledLines.push(lineNumber)
    }
    i += blockSize  
  }

  const top = filledLines.shift()
  const newHeight = filledLines.pop() - top
  return ctx.getImageData(0, top, width , newHeight);
} 

async function trimImage(imageUrl){
  const {img, width, height} = await loadImage(imageUrl)
  // можно создавать временный канвас вне DOM
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  const trimmedImage = trimTransparent(ctx, width, height)
  if (trimmedImage){
    ctx.putImageData(trimmedImage, 0, 0) 
  }
}

trimImage("example.png")
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```